# Ioncube: Is it possible to encrypt an specific function within a PHP file

Tags: ioncube

I have a file called sample.php, that file has PHP and HTML code. I only want to encrypt the PHP function within that file using ioncube. Is it possible?

Comment: I'm 99% sure it's not possible. Maybe you could just move the PHP function into another file?

Comment: @user1578653 Make that 100% with the current version of ionCube. Moving HTML out to a separate file would be the best option (or all PHP functions to a separate PHP file).